# How to see help documentation for RSelenium functions from within RStudio?

Tags: r, rselenium

How do we view docs for functions that are called on objects of `remoteDriver` class (e.g. `remDr` object) from the RSelenium package inside RStudio? For example `remDr$findElement()`

I have tried accessing documentation for a function in a regular way

```
library(RSelenium)

?findElement
?RSelenium::findElement
?RSelenium:::findElement
```

Note: I can see some RSelenium documentation ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf)), but I would like to access docs for methods like `findElement` from within RStudio

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
?RSelenium::remoteDriver
```

Scroll down to see all the methods.